# 'sed' commad is woking if i run the script but if i run the script from java program

Tags: java, shell

I am using 'sed' command in the script. I ran that script directly form my machine. It worked fine and replaced the string i wanted to replace. But when i execute that script form java program using sshconnection, the script is getting executed but the string is not replaced. (sed did not work may be).

My script would look some what like this

```
if grep 'apple' '/opt/dir1/dir2/somescript.sh';
then

    echo "something";

else

    sed -i.bak s/'apple'/'banana'/g /opt/dir1/dir2/somescript.sh;

    rm -rf /tmp/t3.sh

fi
```

The instruction "rm -rf /tmp/t3.sh" is just to check if the script is being called or not. The file 't3.sh' is getting deleted, which means the script is called successfully.

Comment: does the user have access on the file /opt/dir1/dir2/somescript.sh? chown, chmod

Comment: At the top of your script, add the following: `exec 2>/tmp/logfile; set -x` -- then reproduce the bug, and look at the contents of `/tmp/logfile`.

Comment: ...also, you really should have a shebang line if you want consistent behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Seem to be permission issue. It says :                                sed: couldn't open temporary file /opt/dir1/dir2/sednnru1B: Permission denied

Comment: How do i give access to the file somescript.sh ? many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> It says :
>   `sed: couldn't open temporary file /opt/dir1/dir2/sednnru1B: Permission denied`
>
> –  How do i give access to the file ... ?

There are several possibilities.

- You can ssh-connect as a user who has permission to open a temporary file in `/opt/dir1/dir2`.
- You can alter the permissions on `/opt/dir1/dir2` so that the used user account may open a temporary file in this directory.
- If the used user account has permission to write `/opt/dir1/dir2/somescript.sh` and you can do without a `.bak` file in `/opt/dir1/dir2`, this may work:

  ```
      sed s/apple/banana/g  /opt/dir1/dir2/somescript.sh >/tmp/somescript.sh
      cp /tmp/somescript.sh /opt/dir1/dir2/somescript.sh
  ```
- ...